# Catching all declared variables in ESLint

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, eslint, static-code-analysis

**The Story:**

Currently, I'm developing a specific `ESLint` rule ([link](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/10)) to catch all the places where there is a variable that *shadows* a built-in Protractor global variable, like `browser` or `element`.

Here is how the rule looks like at the moment:

```
module.exports = function (context) {
  var protractorGlobals = [
    'browser',
    'protractor',
    'element',
    'by',
    '$',
    '$$'
  ]

  function checkVariables (node) {
    var variables = context.getDeclaredVariables(node)
    for (var i = 0; i < variables.length; ++i) {
      if (protractorGlobals.indexOf(variables[i].name) !== -1) {
        context.report(node, 'Unexpected Protractor built-in global variable shadowing')
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    'VariableDeclaration': checkVariables,
    'FunctionDeclaration': checkVariables,
    'FunctionExpression': checkVariables,
    'CatchClause': checkVariables
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm looking for all variable and function declarations, function expressions, catch clauses and switch statements covering the following cases:

```
var browser = "something";
function test (browser) {};
var browser;
function browser () {};
var browser = 1;
for (var browser = 0; by < 10; ++by) {}
try { json = JSON.parse(input) } catch (browser) {}
```

**The Question:**

Have I covered all the places where a new variable is introduced in a current scope? Is there a *more generic way* to get declared variables anywhere in the code without guessing and explicitly defining the places to look for them?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to you, but you might want to check string function creation functions constructors, eval, setTimeout and setInterval. Not even sure if this is easily possible with eslint.

Comment: see also [Writing an ESLint rule, how to find an exported class, by its identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333552/writing-an-eslint-rule-how-to-find-an-exported-class-by-its-identifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you support ES6, then you are missing `import` declarations. However, there's a slightly easier way to do this. ESLint uses package called Escope under the hood, to track variables declarations and usage. You can take a look at [`no-redeclare`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/no-redeclare.js) rule on how to access it, and refer to [Escope](https://github.com/estools/escope) documentation for information about API. Escope should allow you to check all variables in the current scope and see if you are re-declaring variable that already exists.