# Writing an ESLint rule, how to find an exported class, by its identifier?

Tags: javascript, class, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree, lint

I am writing an ESLint rule for a plugin. I have the following test code:

```js
const test = require('./test');

module.exports.foo = class Foo {}

module.exports.test = class Test {}
```

I have the following rule:

```js
module.exports = {
  create: (context) => ({
    CallExpression: (node) => {
      // The callee must be `require`.
      if (node.callee.name !== 'require') {
        return;
      }

      // Must be part of a VariableDeclarator.
      if (node.parent.type !== 'VariableDeclarator') {
        return;
      }

      const variable = node.parent.id;

      if (variable.type !== 'Identifier') {
        return;
      }

      // Now that we have the variable part of the expression `const name =
      // require('name');`, find any identifiers in the code where the
      // uppercased version of the `variable` is used.
    }
  })
}
```

So as you can see, in the `CallExpression`, I find the `require('./test');` to get the `test` variable name. What I then want to do, as indicated by the final comment in the above code, is to find the class called `Test`. I don't know how to do this. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```js
const scope = context.getScope();

const capitalizedName = variable.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + variable.name.slice(1);

// `undefined` is returned. Why? Shouldn't it find the `Test` class, even if it's exported?
const classVariable = scope.variables.find(variable => variable.name === capitalizedName)

if (!classVariable) {
  return;
}

const foundClassVariable = classVariable.references.find(({ identifier }) =>
  ['ClassDeclaration', 'ClassExpression'].includes(identifier.parent.type),
);
```

Yet it works for the following test code (when the class isn't exported):

```js
const test = require('./test');

class Test {}
```

Anyone know how I can get this to work? Is it possible the problem is with the scope I'm using, and if so, how can I get all the identifiers defined at the document root, to search all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I basically ended up doing:

```js
const scope = context.getScope();

const capitalizedName = variable.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + variable.name.slice(1);

const hasFoundClassVariable = scope.childScopes.some(childScope => childScope.type === 'class' && childScope.variables[0].name === capitalizedName)
```

The [guide here](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/scope-manager-interface) did help, as you would imagine, since it's the official docs.

Comment: Uh, looking up the classes own local scope, thats clever.

Answer (score 0):

You have a *class expression* there, `Test` is just the name of the class that can be used inside the class to reference it, it is not associated to a variable like a *class declaration* is. So in other words: There is no easy way to get that class, you have to manually search through all nodes of the AST and find a *class expression*  that has the name `Test`.

```
  create: (context) => {
    // initialize local variables, e.g. the class names to look for

    return {
      CallExpression: (node) => {
        // register class names
      },
      ClassDeclaration(node) {
        // check class declaration
       },
      ClassExpression(node) {
         // check class expression
      },
   };
 },
```

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. Could you please post some sample code to find the class expression with the name `Test`? Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently searching for the documentation of `node`, I couldn't find one that specifies the prpperties you used ...

Comment: In `create`, I have `const exportedClassNames = []`, then in `ClassExpression`, I push the identifier used for each one to the array. Then I try and access the array in `CallExpression`, but as I suspected, it's empty, because I don't think these blocks can access variables from another block. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: @gary for sure that works *but* the ClassExpression appears in the sourcecode *after* the CallExpression, so in other words you push to the array after you access it.